# Device with compatible configuration is not compatible on the Play Market

Tags: android, google-play, build.gradle

My `build.gradle` default config:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
...
}
```

But for a Samsung Galaxy J1 using Android version 6.0.1 it says that the device is not compatible.

[image]
[image]

**Question:** What can be a reason?

**Note:**
The project uses mixed Kotlin and Java code. What more data should I share to help find an answer?